# On windows “retsize <= sizeInWords” in mbstowcs

Tags: c++, c, c++11

I am getting the error “retsize <= sizeInWords” in mbstowcs. Can someone please guide me as to where am I making mistake.

```
const char *pChar = "[{\]}] ";
int len = strlen(pChar);
wchar_t *str = (wchar_t*)calloc(len+1, sizeof(wchar_t));    // L"";
size_t cSize = len + 1;

mbstowcs_s(&cSize, str, cSize+1, pChar, cSize);
```

Comment: From the doc: [fifth parameter] `count` "The maximum number of wide characters to store in the wcstr buffer, not including the terminating null"

Comment: @Frank: So the correct way should be mbstowcs_s(&cSize, str, cSize, pChar, cSize-1);

Comment: that certainly looks better at a glance.

Comment: Can't reproduce: your example works for me as written, `mbstowcs_s` returns 0 (success) and sets `cSize == 7`. Now, you lie about the size of the buffer pointed to by `str` (the third argument). You tell `mbstowcs_s` it's `len + 2` words large, when in fact it's only `len+1`. But that wouldn't have caused the error you report. The only explanation I have is that the code you've shown is not the code you are actually compiling.